# Word wildcard find & replace puts strings \1 and \2 out of sequence

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards, string

In Word, I want to replace the colons between numbers with "p." to indicate a page number. This is similar to one of most common uses of this feature, to replace hyphens with en dashes ([like in this](https://philgons.com/2009/01/ms-word-tip-how-to-replace-hyphens-with-en-dashes/) and many other sites).

- Search: `([0-9]):([0-9])`
- Replace: `\1, p. \2`
- Result: `1990:123` becomes `1990, p. 32`.

But this only seems to work in some documents. In others, the sequence of the replace strings is wrong:

`1990:123` becomes `1990,1 p. 32`

Somehow word put the second replace string (`\2`, here the number `1`) in between the comma and the p. as the second character.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me why the 1 would somehow end up in the middle of the other characters.
But I've finally found a fix: turn off track changes, as suggested by Mark Jan van Kampen to [this similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/863226/is-there-any-reason-word-2013s-find-replace-using-wildcards-would-replace-thi).